# Save list of pdf file into zip and download it

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm want to download a list of file pdf into an zip file. But when i download it the file pdf inside the zip have size 0kb. i will post the code below.

```
    $this->load->library('zip');

    foreach ($candidati as $candidato)
    {
        if($candidato->CV_candidato){
            $file = $nome . '/' . $candidato->CV_candidato;
            $this->zip->add_data($file);
        }
    }
    $this->zip->download($nome . '.zip');
```

Some suggestion? Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html seems to indicate that `add_data` needs 2 parameters or an array of key/value pairs.

Comment: maybe for download file i must use 'read_file' instead add_data...

Comment: Maybe if you have a file on disk rather than data in a variable you should be using `read_data` yes.

Comment: i have file in remote server

Comment: When you say remote server do you mean somewhere else or the same place where this PHP script is running?

Comment: not in the same place

Comment: Well you can probably use : `$this->zip->add_data(basename($file),file_get_contents($file));`

Comment: @apokryfos I tried with your code but when i cant inzip the file because its damaged.

Comment: check if it helps you roytuts.com/backup-site-and-database-in-codeigniter/         and roytuts.com/create-archive-or-zip-using-php/

Comment: i solved. Thank you for your help.